# Using mount_ftp command in MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, ftp, mount

I want to include a ftp share into my normal filesystem by performing the following commands:

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/myfolder
$ mount_ftp ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.tld /Volumes/myfolder
```

I get no error message, but when I open the folder, the folder is just empty. I also tried to follow the instructions listed [here](https://igppwiki.ucsd.edu/groups/publichelpwiki/wiki/d0cc0/How_to_Mount_an_FTP_Server_on_Mac_OSX.html), but I receive the error "The share does not exist on the server. Please check the share name, and then try again.". However, I can access to the share by typing ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.tld into my adress bar.

Any ideas what I could do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you'll see in `man mount_ftp`, `mount_ftp` can set several return values.  One way to get the return value is to say `echo $?` right after the `mount_ftp` command.